# how to get tkinter GUI features in Code-server on Android

Tags: android, tkinter, termux, code-server

I installed code-server in ubuntu in termux on android device. It is ok for CUI. Tkinter has problem - 'couldn't connect to display :1'. I've tried some ways I found in googling but not solved the problem. Is there any way to run GUI in code-server in termux linux using tkinter. I'm beginner in linux.

Comment: `tkinter` can't be used on android, it also requires a display so you can't run it on a server that doesn't have a display

Comment: Some said X forwarding as a solution. But I don't know what is is. Please help me.

Comment: You can read about [Graphical Environment](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment) in Termux.

Comment: You need to enable `X11Forwarding` of `sshd` in `Termux`, then you can connect to `Termux` via ssh with X11 forwarding from other machine with X11 server.  For Windows platform, you can try `MobaXterm` which is a ssh client with built-in X11 server.

Comment: Thank you and deeply sorry for my very late response. I'm now stop trying to get GUI in code-server, and instead, try to start using Vim in Termux with Xfce4.